# Undesired backslashes when reading a html with rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, backslash

I am trying to read a website using rvest, my code as follows:

```
pg <- read_html("https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/archivo/prensa?utf8=%E2%9C%93&idiom=es&style=list&order=DESC&filter_id=&filter_origin=archive&tags=&year=&category=Discursos+del+Presidente&year=&category=Discursos+del+Presidente")
```

However, when I read "pg" I get double backslashes between html-classes, like in the following snippet:

```
<a class='\\"small-link\\"' href="%5C%22/presidencia/es/prensa/epn-palabras-134612?idiom=es%5C%22" target='\\"_blank\\"'>
```

This does not occur when I read other websites:

```
pg2 <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0245712/")
#output: <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n
```

Any idea why this might happen? I really want to get rid of it, since it hinders me from retrieving data with html_nodes():

```
pg  %>%
  html_nodes(".small-link")
#output: {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

**Update!**

1. This error seems to happen only when using rvest with Mexican IPs :/
2. Following a [suggestion below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47359346/3432632), I tried using regex to clean my object ("pg").

So when looking at pg div classes have these double backslashes like this:

```
pg 
#Result: <div class='\\"col-md-12' small-bottom-buffer>
```

If I clean pg trying to delete one backslash it seems to work and I only have one left:

```
pg2 <- gsub("\\\\", "", pg)
pg2
#Result: <div class='\"col-md-12' small-bottom-buffer>
```

However, if I try to delete both backslashes, I get three back instead!:

```
pg3 <- gsub("\\\\\\\\", "", pg)
pg3
#<div class='\\\"col-md-12' small-bottom-buffer>
```

I don't understand this behaviour

Comment: I can't reproduce this; it works fine for me. Update, maybe? It looks like the quotes aren't getting parsed for some reason; the backslashes are there to show you they're part of the text, not as a string demarcation.

Comment: Yes, [others have said](https://twitter.com/RLadiesMAD/status/931421919433379840) they can't reproduce this mistake, however, everyone in Mexico gets the same mistake for some reason, can that just be a coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with rvest to provide an rvest solution, but you can use readLines and grep to find the data you're looking for. You can then use REGEX to clean it up

```
pg3 <- readLines("https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/archivo/prensa?utf8=%E2%9C%93&idiom=es&style=list&order=DESC&filter_id=&filter_origin=archive&tags=&year=&category=Discursos+del+Presidente&year=&category=Discursos+del+Presidente")

grep('<a class=\"small-link\"', pg3, value = TRUE)
grep('<a class="small-link"', pg3, value = TRUE)
grep('<a class=\\"small-link\\"', pg3, value = TRUE)
```

All three work. The reason you are seeing \" is because \ is an escape character, and " is a special character since it's used to input character data into R. For example:

```
> print("test"test")
Error: unexpected symbol in "print("test"test"
> print('test"test')
[1] "test\"test"
> print("test\"test")
[1] "test\"test"
```